# Phantomjs loading resource error "Connection closed" in SUSE Linux

Tags: phantomjs

When open URL using SSL in Phantomjs( v 1.9.8 ), I face the problem: Resource request error "Connection closed".

OS info: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12

The command line like this:

```
phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any --debug=true rasterize.js https://192.168.70.57:8072/upgrade.html test.png
```

The detail logs:

```
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] CookieJar - Created but will not store cookies (use option '--cookies-file=' to enable persisten cookie storage) 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] Phantom - execute: Configuration 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] 0 objectName : "" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] 1 cookiesFile : "" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] 2 diskCacheEnabled : "false" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] 3 maxDiskCacheSize : "-1" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] 4 ignoreSslErrors : "true" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] 5 localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled : "false" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] 6 outputEncoding : "UTF-8" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] 7 proxyType : "http" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] 8 proxy : ":1080" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] 9 proxyAuth : ":" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] 10 scriptEncoding : "UTF-8" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] 11 webSecurityEnabled : "true" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] 12 offlineStoragePath : "" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] 13 offlineStorageDefaultQuota : "-1" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] 14 printDebugMessages : "true" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] 15 javascriptCanOpenWindows : "true" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] 16 javascriptCanCloseWindows : "true" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] 17 sslProtocol : "any" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] 18 sslCertificatesPath : "" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] 19 webdriver : ":" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] 20 webdriverLogFile : "" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] 21 webdriverLogLevel : "INFO" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] 22 webdriverSeleniumGridHub : "" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] Phantom - execute: Script & Arguments 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] script: "rasterize.js" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] 0 arg: "https://192.168.70.57:8072/upgrade.html" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] 1 arg: "chick.png" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] Phantom - execute: Starting normal mode 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame "" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/fs.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )

2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/system.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )

2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/_coffee-script.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )

2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/package.json" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )

2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )

2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/./lexer.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )

2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/././rewriter.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )

2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/././helpers.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )

2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/./parser.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )

2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/./helpers.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )

2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/./nodes.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )

2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/././scope.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )

2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/./././helpers.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )

2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/././lexer.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )

2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/./././rewriter.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )

2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/webpage.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )

2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 10 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] **Network - Resource request error: 2 ( "Connection closed" ) URL: "https://192.168.70.57:8072/upgrade.html"** 


2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 100 
Unable to load the address!
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame "" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/fs.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )

2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/system.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )

2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/_coffee-script.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )

2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/webpage.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )

2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 10 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame "" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/fs.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )

2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/system.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )

2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/_coffee-script.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )

2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/webpage.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )

2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 100 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 10 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 100 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame "" 
2015-03-10T17:59:45 [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame ""
```

Comment: Try updating to PhantomJS 2.

Comment: Have you build PhantomJS 2 for Linux yet? Please provide binary packages for Linux (64bit). Thanks so much.

Comment: It's easy, simply follow the [build instructions](http://phantomjs.org/build.html). I just finished a build on a raspberrypi.

Comment: I've built Phantomjs 2.0 for SUSE 12, but I still get same issue. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I am also seeing the same issue with PhantomJS 2... Resource request error: 2 - Connection Closed. No other browsers have this issue to the same site.

Comment: Oddly; when using fiddler to examine what's happening at the HTTP level; the resource request errors disappear. :-/

Comment: @daveL Thanks for the idea. When I used Charles Proxy, I saw that my HTTPS request was being rejected because it was using SSLv3. When I switched to TLSv1, it worked.